Get sub-objects in JSON where key values unknown
I have the following JSON generated from a command.  The JSON is composed of objects where the key is a random string, and I want to access data in each of those objects.  Any thoughts on how to do that, without knowing the value of the key for each object?
{
  "provisionInfo": {
    "2b66706e-237c-4d05-b3c0-31b03186b9e5": {
      "Status": "Up",
      "key": "value"
    },
    "3fb6886e-9877c-4d05-b39f-31b03186b9e5": {
      "Status": "Up",
      "key": "value"
    }
  }
}

I know I can do this to get the objects:
$ cat tmp.json | jq -c '.provisionInfo'

{"2b66706e-237c-4d05-b3c0-31b03186b9e5":{"Status":"Up","key":"value"},"3fb6886e-9877c-4d05-b39f-31b03186b9e5":{"Status":"Up","key":"value"}}

But how do I access the value of Status for both objects without knowing the index?

Have a look at the Array/Object Value Iterator .[] in the manual, and try jq -r '.provisionInfo[].Status'
